# infinite scroll from external json in angularjs

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I have a bit of trouble as creating an infinite scroll in angularjs from a JSON file generated on an external site. What I need is that the infinite scroll is called when the item of variable posts equals 10, again calling my function, increasing +1 in the url, changing the page. Follow the code:

```
$scope.posts = [];
    $scope.doRefresh = function(){
        JsonNews.getBlogs($scope);
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    }
$page = 0;
    function JsonNews($http, $log){
        $page++;
        $urlInfinite = "http://plantaojti.com.br/noticias/page/"+ $page +"/?feed=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
        this.getBlogs = function($scope){
            $http.jsonp($urlInfinite).success(function(data){
                $scope.posts = data;
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.posts.length; i++) {
                    this.posts.push(posts[i].data);
                }
                AppCtrl.$scope.doRefresh($scope);
            });
        }
    }
```

In HTML:

```
<div infinite-scroll='JsonNews()' inite-scroll-distance='1'>
        <ion-item data-ng-repeat="item in posts | filter: query" class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap item-icon-right" href="window.open('{{item.permalink}}', '_system', 'location=yes'">
                    <img class="thumb-noticia" data-ng-src="{{item.thumbnail}}">
                    <h2> {{item.title}} </h2>
                    <p>{{item.excerpt | limitTo: 100}}...</p>
         </ion-item>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is a custom directive, please post the directive code.  If it's a plugin, please share a link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could then solve ... I used to tag the Ionic  in HTML, see:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="80%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

And with a small function, I solved the problem ...

```
$scope.loadMore = function(){
      JsonNews.getBlogs($scope);
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
  }
function JsonNews($http, $scope, $log){
  this.getBlogs = function($scope){
    $urlInfinite = "http://plantaojti.com.br/noticias/page/"+ $page + "/?feed=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    $page++;
    $http.jsonp($urlInfinite).success(function(data){
      $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(data);
    });
  }
}
```